# asp.net buttons generated programmatically

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am generating buttons programmatically. They are the answers to a question. A question can have 2..* answers. when a user clicks on an answer his action is recorded in a database.
Now, In order to know on which button a user clicked, I decided to create a datagrid with only a CommandField Select column. this will allow me to determine which row was selected in the codebehind.

Problem: Can I bind the text of the CommandField Select? I want the text to be the answer not just the text "Select" on each row.

Do you suggest another solution to my problem?

I need something like
how old are you?

0-18 //answer1 (Command Field)

18-21

greater than 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most people would use the ***[RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)*** or ***[CheckboxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)*** for that sort of thing.  If you follow the links, you will find examples of both. I would probably go that route instead of a DataGrid. That's typically for displaying tabular data for viewing/editing purposes.  That's just my 2 cents, though.

Comment: Ok, radioButtonList with autopostback is what I need. Though, I would like to change the item teamplate, to make the radio button look like a button. Can I do this?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure.  I've never tried.  I would think you would be able to, but that kind of defeats the purpose of them being radio buttons.